Given the sum of two dice, find the probability of the die landing on each side
This was a question posed to me in a mathematics course, and I could not solve it,

Given a $n$-sided die (could be fair or not). You throw it twice and record the sum (there is no dependance between the throws). If you are only given the histogram of the sums can you use it to know which are the probabilities of the die landing on each side?
The histogram contains the probabilities of various sums.

The answer is that yes, you can find find the probabilities of each side landing regardless whether the die is fair or not.
I was able to find equations to solve when the die is fair,
P(sum = 2) = p(X = 1) * p(Y =1) = p(X=1)^2 --> we can find p(X = 1) as both are the same
P(sum = 3) = 2*p(X = 1)*p(Y = 2) --> we can use the p(X=1) here and the equations continue
but can someone provide a detailed explanation with an example when the die is not fair.

When you say the "histogram of the sums", it that the histogram of observed sums from a sample of rolls; or is it the histogram of the actual (theoretical) probabilities of the various sums?

"The answer is that yes,you can find find the probabilities of each side landing regardless whether the dice is fair or not" : depends on what you intend here.  Suppose for example that the probability of a $~6~$ is $~p > (1/6),~$ and that the die is otherwise fair.  Further, suppose that two rolls of the die summed to $~10,~$ which implies that you either rolled 4-6, 5-5, or 6-4.  The only way that you can determine (for example) whether you rolled a 5-5 here, is if the value of the variable $~\mathbf{p}~$ is known.

Yeah histogram of sums refers to the probabilities of various sums

As a simple example, imagine you are throwing a four sided die.  You will find the sums run from $2$ to $8$.  The $2$ can only come from throwing $1$ twice, so the chance of a $1$ is the square root of the chance of a sum of $2$.  Similarly the chance of a $4$ is the square root of the chance of a sum of $8$.  Now a $3$ comes from $1+2$ so you can use the chance of a sum of $3$ and the known chance of a $1$ from a die to get the chance of a $2$.
This will work even if the numbers do not run from $1$ to $n$.  The minimum sum will be twice the lowest number on the die and the highest sum will be twice the highest number on the die.  The next lowest sum will be the lowest number plus the second lowest number.  If a number is duplicated you will find the chance of getting either of the faces with that number.  If you throw two different dice this is not guaranteed to work.  If you have two fair dice, one numbered $1,3,4,5,6,8$ and one numbered $1,2,2,3,3,4$ the sums are distributed the same as normal six sided dice.
